# How do I make a multi item table order list for Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce

I have several items that should be allowed to be ordered on one page using Drupal Commerce. Take the example of dairy products. There should be a table of dairy items a person can purchase such as milk, cream, butter, and cream cheese. Each of these items should be viewed as a row of a table in the dairy page. The customer should be able to mark the number of each item they want to purchase and submit the form using a purchase button at the bottom of the table. How is this done using Drupal Commerce? The checkout view does just this. Is it possible to create views that do this too?

Here is an image of the checkout form that does this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Commerce Add to Cart Extras module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras). You can use this with Views to build your own lists of products and add multiple quantities of multiple products with one click.